# fgets cutting off input after 3rd character

Tags: c

I have a function to take in and format user input, but it keeps cutting off the input after the 3rd character.

```
void formatInput(char *input_variable) {
    fgets(input_variable, sizeof(input_variable), stdin);
    strtok(input_variable, "\n");
}

int main() {
    char input_string[255];
    printf("Enter input: ");
    formatInput(&input_string[0]);

   return 0;
}
```

If I enter `myinput` then it gets stored as `myi`. If I don't wrap it in this function, then it works perfectly fine.

Comment: `gets(input_variable, sizeof(input_variable), stdin);` sizeof will yield the size of a **pointer**. (which appears to be 4 on your machine)

Comment: @wildplasser Am I not passing the same value to `fgets` in that function as I would if I were to call it in `main()` then? I thought they would both be the address of the first element of the array. How would I get the size of the entire array from within the function then?

Comment: Ooops, the `f` fell off while cut&pasting ...

Comment: As seen by the function, there is no array. The only thing the function can see is the pointer. Which could basically point to *anything*, even a single character. Or it could be NULL. The function cannot tell.

Comment: You must pass the size of the array to your function.

Comment: @wildplasser Ah I see. That makes sense.

Comment: @M.NejatAydin I'll do this then. Thanks!

Comment: BTW the `strtok(input_variable, "\n");` does nothing; you are not using its return value.

Comment: @wildplasser I don't need its return value. It's still modifying my original string and removing the newline.

Comment: You are correct.